# I try to display a PDF, but I always see an empty page

Tags: reactjs

I try in vain to display a PDF file that is sent via a REST interface.
The BLOB is there, not empty. I always get an empty PDF. No mistake.

```
 const getPdf = (id) => {
 const fetchData = async () => {
   const data = await axios
    .get("http://XXXXXX:xxx/xx/xx", {
      params: {
        _id: id,
        gesuchtNach: wert,
        firmenId: "555",
        kundenId: "123",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = "Report_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
      link.click();

      /* ALSO TRIED - SAME PROBLEM
      const file = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      FileSaver.saveAs(file, "file.pdf");

       */
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
 };
fetchData();
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the very same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think you could use [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) to show your pdf file. It's very easy to use.

Basically, you have just to pass pdf file to `Document` component like:

```
  <Document
    file="somefile.pdf"
    onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} // function to manage loading succedd
  >
    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
  </Document>
```

[Here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/displaying-pdf-in-react-app-6e9d1fffa1a9) an how-to about react-pdf for first steps, and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/displaying-pdf-using-react-5d003?from-embed) a working example.

Comment: No, it wasn't. I only want to display a PDF using the existing methods

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of frontend, Add responseType:'blob' in Axios params,

Original answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677549/14806412