# Trying to view data as pdf , pdf is blank

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, pdf, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to open a pdf file in the next tab, it opens but is always blank. I am calling a pdf file from a folder in my springboot. The data does show in the console log .

Spring code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "test123.pdf";
        String path = "TrainingDocuments/SuperPartnerUser/" + fileName;

        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());

    }
```

React code:

```
function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
         element.setAttribute('target','_blank');
       
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
       
        element.click();
       
        document.body.removeChild(element);
        }

    function test () {
        Api(`tempFileDownload/report`, 'Get',"",3).then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            download("test",data)
            const file = new Blob([ data ], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            //Build a URL from the file
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //Open the URL on new Window
            window.open(fileURL);
        });
}
```

[Pdf data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMx90.png)
[Blank PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opvjM.png)

Comment: is the data you are receiveing from API base64?

Comment: @MujeebQureshi dont believe it is?

Comment: yea cause you are sending binary data from your server, that you seems to be placing inside a Blob object on your front end.
Did you try console logging `fileURL` just after `const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);`

Comment: @MujeebQureshi when I console log the file url i get the Blob size and type

Comment: @MujeebQureshi is this correct?

Comment: I believe thats the issue, It should be a URL string instead of an object.

Comment: @MujeebQureshi can you recommend a solution to fix the issue, for me everything look good>

Comment: Is it possible for you to return a base64 string of the pdf report instead of binary?
Things will get real easy f you can manage this.
If your server is written on dotNet there is a simple utility that can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue was the api call for the frontend, backend works fine;
Reponse type needed to be blob

```
const result = await axios({
            url: `${localUrl + url}`, //your url
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob', // important
        })
        .then(({ data }) => data);
    return result;
```